# Can I carryover investment interest expenses, if I didn't report them on a prior tax form

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction, irs

I just discovered some investment interest expenses from a broker statement that were not reported in my last year tax return.

Can I "carry them over" into my new tax return? Its probably an accounting flag, but I have the broker statement if necessary. More so wondering if that ship has simply sailed, as some tax reportings and elections really are time constricted.

Comment: Any reason you don't want to file an amended return for the previous year?

Comment: @Joe because the amounts aren't relatively large, I suppose

Comment: @Joe and it wouldn't affect anything I paid or received back from the government that year, as there weren't capital gains reported, just expenses. (For example, if I was short selling Valeant Pharmaceuticals in 2015 until now, the margin would be an interest expense I incurred that year)